# Rspec error: undefined method `permanent'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, session-cookies, factory-bot

I'm trying to test signing in on my ruby app but I keep getting the error: undefined method `permanent' for the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Logging in", :type => :request do
  it "Signs in valid user" do

    val_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    get signin_path
    expect(response).to be_success
    sign_in(val_user)
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(response).to render_template(root_path)
    expect(flash[:success]).to be_present


  end
end
```

spec/support/utilities.rb

```
module Utilities

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies[:remember_token] =  user.remember_token
    request.session[:user] = user.id
  end

end
```

I had previously had my sign_in method in a spec_test_helper.rb file in spec/support but another post on stack overflow had told me to move it to utilities and to remove .permanent from the line:

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] =  user.remember_token
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
 # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:4:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/log_in_spec.rb:10:in `(root)'
 # org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1562:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:612:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:549:in `run_examples'
 # org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2412:in `map'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:545:in `run_examples'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `run_specs'
 # org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2412:in `map'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `(root)'
 # org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087:in `load'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/bin/rspec:1:in `(root)'
 # org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1107:in `eval'
 # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15:in `(root)'
```

Please help!

Comment: so you removed the .permanent method but are still getting an undefined method error on it?

Comment: What's at `./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:4`?

Comment: oh there's another sign in helper also named sign_in. When I try to change the utility function name, the spec isn't recognizing it. I required it in my spec helper.